# Create function that accept arguments of any type (like concat)

Tags: postgresql, create-function

How can I create function that accepts arguments of any type.

I can create function like this:
`CREATE FUNCTION test(anyelement,anyelement) ...`

But when I call it, I have to present arguments of same type:

```
SELECT test(1,2); -- ok
```

But:

```
SELECT test('lalala',2); -- error
```

Can I create a function that will accept arguments of any type, then cast them to string and do something with this strings.

So, can I create function that will look like `concat(str "any" [, str "any" [, ...] ])`

UPD: updated second example

Comment: ERROR:  function test(character varying, integer) does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple alternative. Every type can be cast to `text`. You can just create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test(text, text [,text [, ...]]) ...
```

And call it:

```
SELECT test('lalala'::text,2::text);
```

Just cast each argument to text explicitly.